# Decomposing strings in Android Application

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am trying to write an Android Application in Java for an Android phone. The Android application reads serial data strings via Bluetooth using SPP profile. These strings are sent by another Bluetooth device. These strings are in the following format:

```
"Acc Data:x_adc,y_adc,z_adc!"
```

Each string begins with:

> "Acc Data:

and ends with

> "!"

The x_adc, y_adc and z_adc are values and have a length of 5 digits.

These strings are sent at regular intervals. Right now I am able to use `InputStream` to accept these strings using a string buffer. I'm also able to display the complete strings in a scrollable TextView which displays each string beneath the other.

What I want to do is to decompose the x_adc, y_adc and z_adc values from the strings and display these values in a 3 separate TextViews. The TextViews which need to display the adc values have to refresh after a new string has been sent to the Android smartphone. I tried to use the Pattern class and split() to decompose the strings but failed to understand them and use them in the application.

Could someone help me with this problem?

Comment: What did you try? Why did it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
    private TextView tv1;
    private TextView tv2;
    private TextView tv3;

    update("Acc Data:x_adc,y_adc,z_adc!");

    public void update(String data) {
        String values[] = data.replace("Acc Data:", "").replace("!", "").split(",");
        String v1 = "";
        String v2 = "";
        String v3 = "";
        if(values != null && values.length == 3) {
            v1 = values[0];
            v2 = values[1];
            v3 = values[2];
        }
        tv1.setText(v1);
        tv2.setText(v2);
        tv3.setText(v3);
    }
```

Alternate way of getting the values:

```
String values[] = data.substring(data.indexOf(':') + 1, data.indexOf('!')).split(",");
```

Comment: Hello britzl,
Thanks for your help. Your example works!
Greetings Willem

Answer (score 2):

You could use `substring()` to clean the extra data, and then `split()`:

```
String[] values = indata.substring(9, 26).split(",");
String x_adc = values[0];
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just have a lood at the String functions `substring(beginIndex, endIndex)` to suppress the static part of the string and `split(",")` to get the 3 values.

Answer (score 0):

This code will handles instances where > 3 tokens are included in the `String`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String value = "Acc Data:x_adc,y_adc,z_adc!";

    String trimmed = value.substring(value.indexOf(":")+1, value.length()-1);
    String[] tokens = trimmed.split(",");

    for(String token: tokens){
        System.out.println(token);
    }
}
```